# Get balance of a specific token in python using web3.py on polygon network

Tags: web3.py, polygon

I am trying to get the balance in my wallet of specific tokens with no luck.
I have found examples online on how to do this task using web3.js, but the methods used seem to be different. I also found this helpful example: [How to view custom token balance in ether wallet using web3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36790/how-to-view-custom-token-balance-in-ether-wallet-using-web3/36798), however it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Is anyone able to provide a short script that can do this?

As an example, on the polygon network I expect the wallet address 0x0598acaf4eA05D41844b23423ff4E2d9Cf2b481E to contain 0.882 USDT. Is there anyway to get this programmatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the token's ABI and utilize the function `balanceOf`. Example snippet below:

```
token = w3.eth.contract(address={token address}, abi={token abi}) # declaring the token contract
token_balance = token.functions.balanceOf({your address}).call() # returns int with balance, without decimals
```

You can find the token ABI [from the block explorer](https://explorer-mainnet.maticvigil.com), from the code tab of your token. In your case, [here](https://explorer-mainnet.maticvigil.com/address/0xc2132D05D31c914a87C6611C10748AEb04B58e8F/contracts) you can find the ABI for USDT's contract. You will need to parse JSON before being able to use it in Python.

Comment: It has `balanceOf` API. What you are linking is the API to [upgradeable proxy contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/upgradeable-smart-contracts) that transparently passes the calls through.

Comment: Is there a way to do this via discovery instead of having prior knowledge of the tokens?

Answer (score 1):

You need the contract's ABI, but any ERC20 standard ABI will do.

```
def get_balance(user_address):
       contract_address = "0x2791Bca1f2de4661ED88A30C99A7a9449Aa84174"
       infura_url = 'https://polygon-mainnet.infura.io/v3/<infura api key>'
       web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))
       contract = 
       web3.eth.contract(address=Web3.toChecksumAddress(contract_address.lower()), abi=abi)
       balance = contract.functions.balanceOf(Web3.toChecksumAddress(user_address.lower())).call()
       return balance
```